# Is it custom file extension?

Tags: lua

So basically I have 3 files with custom extensions: .dif9, .tif9, .cif9
I would like to open it somehow but I have no idea how, do you have any ideas?

Those are the files: https://github.com/fleuter21/dif9

Just how to open them.

Answer (score 2):

`file` in Linux says:

```
egg_data.cif9: RenderWare collision data (COL), version 3, used in GTA SA
egg_data.dif9: RenderWare data, v3.6.0.3, used in GTA SA, 3D models (DFF)
egg_data.tif9: RenderWare data, v3.6.0.3, used in GTA SA, texture archive (TXD)
```

does that look plausible to you? If yes, then look for a RenderWare converter or parser.

Comment: I actually knew these are some kind of files related to GTA SA, but I still had no idea how to open them properly.